# Lazy Loading Problem : Cannot match any routes. URL Segment

Tags: angular, .net-core

I am working on the Angular 11 version. Used the lazy loading. But at that time of running the application it shows me an error. Also

```
<a [routerLink]="['/Login']">Login</a>
<a [routerLink]="['/student/Add']">Student</a>
```

Break the project into two folders 1) Home, here is the **home.routing.ts file code.**

```
const routes: Routes = [
 
  {path:'Login',component:UserLoginComponent},
  {path:'student',
    loadChildren:()=>import('../Student/Student.module').then(m=>m.StudentModule),
  canActivate:[MyAuthGuard]}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class HomeRoutingModule { }
```

2. Student Folder, **Student.Routing.ts file**

```
const Studentroutes: Routes = [

 {path:'Add',component:StudentComponent},

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(Studentroutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class StudentRoutingModule { }
```

Here is the **UserLogin.Component.ts** file Button click event.

```
  Add(){
    alert(this.stuMNGTObj.name);
    var observable = this.httpClient.post(this.config.apiUrl+"home/Insert",this.stuMNGTObj);
    observable.subscribe(res=>this.Sucess(res),res=>this.Error(res)); 
    alert("Conti"); 
}
```

Comment: What is the error that it shows?

Comment: @Sam  Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'student/Add'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'student/Add

Comment: Have you defined Router.forChild() in your StudentModule, passing in your feature routes `Studentroutes`?

Comment: @Sam yes please check the code... I have updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added StudentRoutingModule to imports of StudentModule?